# Is there a WYSIWYG editor that can be installed on Virto commerce?

Tags: virtocommerce

Is there a proper functioning WYSIWYG editor that can be installed on Virtocommerce?

If not is there a way that one could be installed using a plugin from another source?

Comment: What do you mean by "WYSIWYG editor"? Do you want to edit pages, blog post and other *.md files?

Answer (score 1):

VirtoCommerce uses Markdown language for user-prepared documents and a custom solution based on [uikit HTML editor](https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/htmleditor.html) with preview:

[image]

Although this is a highly customizable and extensible framework, the default editor (used in current UI) can't be changed by a setting or installing a new plugin.

But you can use any other editor in your own module.